# Density plot of a vector shows tails before and after its minimum and maximum

Tags: r, kernel-density, density-plot

I have the following vector:

```
v<-c(1, 1, 8, 3, 1, 9, 4, 21, 13, 13, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 13, 22, 1, 
1, 4, 2, 1, 13, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 12, 10, 26, 15, 2, 9, 6, 
5, 1, 3, 18, 2, 10, 2, 8, 9, 4, 1, 11, 4, 2, 12, 3, 14, 2, 1, 
27, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1, 3, 16, 3, 36, 13, 9, 11, 10, 24, 2, 27, 4, 
4, 2, 9, 1, 3, 13, 3, 1, 8, 5, 5, 15, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 14, 8, 1, 
1, 2, 20, 1, 9, 3, 1, 2, 5, 14, 5, 11, 1, 3, 2, 9, 10, 21, 9, 
1, 20, 5, 11, 23, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 2, 9, 1, 19, 9, 9, 2, 15, 
17, 8, 11, 17, 2, 14, 2, 8, 13, 1, 2, 9, 15, 25, 3, 8, 32, 4, 
11, 1, 1, 2)
```

I would like to estimate its density in `R` through the command `density`. With few lines of code:

```
d<-density(v)
df<-data.frame(x=d$x,y=d$y,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plot(df)
```

I obtained the following picture:

[image]

But the resulting plot doesn't add up, because `max(v)` is 36 and `min(v)` is 1 while the graph shows tails before and after 0 and 40.

Comment: When I run the `density` I get -5 as min and 42 as max

Comment: That's what `density` does, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436835/why-density-plot-tails-are-beyond-maximum-and-minimum-values). "The aim is to approximate the underlying distribution; so, outside the data range the estimate will have comparably small density values which means lack of data around these points might suggest that the probability of having the next samples around here is low, but not impossible."

Comment: you are probably just searching for `hist(v, breaks = seq(0, max(v), 1))`

Comment: Think about it logically. If there were no tails outside of the maximum and minimum values of `v`, then the density line would have to touch the x axis at these points. That means that the density would be 0 at the maximum and minimum points of `v`. But a probability density of 0 means that it is not possible to draw that value from the distribution. Clearly, these values _have_ been drawn from the distribution, so by definition the probability density is _not_ 0 at your maximum and minimum `v` values.